# How do i expand the width of the parallax images to full width and height

Tags: html, css

How do i expand the parallax images to cover the full screen width and height up to the navigation. 
I can't seem to get it past the containers.
I have tried removing the margin parameters on the container
I have tried giving the parallax class a full width of 100% as well, didn't do anything.
Basically i want the top half rather to look like this. http://www.toonsville.co.uk/aboutus.html rather than have container edges. Currently it looks like this http://toonsville.co.uk/learn.html

```css
 body,html{
    height: 100%;



   }




    .container{
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: #ffcc66;
     font-size: 24px;
     padding: 50px;
     position: relative;
     }

    .parallax {
     min-height: 400px;
     background: transparent;
     }

    .container img{
     height: 10em;
     position: absolute;
     left: 40em;
     top:11em;
     z-index: 1;
     }


     h2{
     color:#FFD;
     font-size:3em;
     font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
     padding-top: 4em;
     padding-left: 1em;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     }

    .innercontainer{
     background-color:#ffcc66;
     padding: 2em;


    }

   .aboutus {


    background-color: #ffd;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;    
    padding: 2em;
    border: 4px solid darkred;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    box-shadow: 6px 7px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    }
```

```html
<body>

    <nav>

        <header class="clearfix">

            <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Search</a>
                <a href="aboutus.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> About us</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>Contact us</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>Shop</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </nav>
    <title>The about us page</title>


    <div class="container">


        <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1" data-image- src="images/moudarkbackground.png"
            data-speed="0.3">
            <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
        </div>
        <img src="images/timon.png">
        <div class="innercontainer">
            <p class="aboutus">Whether you’re an executive accountant, work in a

                factory or even a policeman, we all have one thing in common.
                most of us have had the same conversion at
                least once within the last 5 years.
                Now you’re thinking that I’m possibly just making things up.
                The conversation starts off something to this effect:
                “Do you remember the cartoon?” We look at classic cartoons.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1" data-image-src="images/classictoons5.png">
            <h2>saturday morning nostalgia!</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</body>
```

How do i expand the parallax images to cover the full screen width and height up to the navigation. 
I can't seem to get it past the containers.
I have tried removing the margin parameters on the container
I have tried giving the parallax class a full width of 100% as well, didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try giving background image in parallax CSS.

```
.parallax {
            min-height: 400px;
            background: transparent;
            background-image: url(images/moudarkbackground.png);
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

background-size: **cover**; Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort guys, it's still not working. Basically what i'm trying to achieve is from http://www.toonsville.co.uk/learn.html  to http://www.toonsville.co.uk/aboutus.html   (so that the image fully takes the full width like the first one, and no contained edges )

Comment: in learn.html you have container div that has margin and padding set, that is causing the problem

Comment: Also you may want to try background-size: cover; to scale the image.

Comment: Ah mate, thanks so much, it has finally worked! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give the body the background image you want to use in your CSS...

For Example:

```
 <html>
<style>
body {
 background: url('image.jpg')
}
</style>

<body>

My Name is......

</body>


</html>
```

That way, it will be at the back of everything in the body tag...

Do you understand that?

Comment: mmm no that hasn't worked i'm afraid. I think that might work if i just needed a fixed image in the background, but im doing the dynamic parallax layout.